# Refactor by defining method for Array of Hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, refactoring, conditional-statements

I am trying to refactor my code by defining a conditional method.
The current code functions perfectly, but I need to refactor it thoroughly while maintaining the existing structure and readability.

---

In this scenario, the user is asked to make a selection.  That selection is associated with a symbol in an array of hashes.  The method  should replace the last two `puts` in this sample below.  The  code prints these two lines over and over.

```
puts"Red, white, or something else?"
user_category_selection = gets.chomp.downcase
puts "-"*80

wine_rack = [
  { name: "The Fugitive",
    vintage: 2010,
    category: "Red",
    grape_composition: "Red Blend",
    location: "Napa, California",
    personal_rating: 91},

  { name: "Au Bon Climat",
    vintage: 2010,
    category: "White",
    grape_composition: "Chardonnay",
    location: "Santa Barbara, California",
    personal_rating: 89},

  { name: "Laurent-Perrier",
    vintage: "Non-vintage",
    category: "Something Else",
    grape_composition: "Ultra Brut",
    location: "France",
    personal_rating: 92}
]
```

This is the piece that is not functioning:

```
def vintage_name_location(category)
  category = wine_rack[:category].downcase
  while category.downcase.include? user_category_selection
    puts "#{wine[:vintage]}    #{wine[:name]}, #{wine[:location]}".center(80)
    puts "#{wine[:grape_composition]}, rated #{wine[:personal_rating]} points".center(80)
  end
end
puts vintage_name_location(user_category_selection)
```

The rest of the code is:

```
until ["white", "red", "something else"].include? user_category_selection.downcase
  puts "Pardon me for asking, but are you intoxicated already?".center(80)
  puts "I said red, white, or something else.".center(80)
  user_category_selection = gets.chomp
end

if user_category_selection.downcase.eql? "red"
  puts "May I suggest one of these delightful reds:"
  puts "--------------------------------------------------".center(80)
  for wine in wine_rack
    if wine[:category].downcase == user_category_selection
      puts "#{wine[:vintage]}    #{wine[:name]}, #{wine[:location]}".center(80)
      puts "#{wine[:grape_composition]}, rated #{wine[:personal_rating]} points".center(80)
      puts "--------------------------------------------------".center(80)
    end
  end
elsif user_category_selection.downcase.eql? "white"
```

Comment: You might consider constructing a hash `category_to_wines` so that in the "rest of code", `category_to_wines[user_category_selection.downcase]` gives you the list of wines (hashes) to recommend.  You could do that as follows: `category_to_wines = wine_rack.each_with_object({}) { |wine, h| (h[wine[:category].downcase] ||= []) << wine }`. For each key "category" (downcased), its value is an array of those wines (hashes) that match on the category. Looking at the bigger picture, you should consider using a database for your application.

Comment: I'd recommend *not* using `for` loops. The Ruby-way is to iterate using `each` or `map`. Maintain indenting in your code as a debugging/maintenance aide as it'll really help you in the long run. Your code isn't complete. Please read "[mcve]". We need something syntactically correct.

Comment: Thank you Tin Man - at the moment I am purposely using loops for further practice.  I completely agree with you.  The code wasn't published in it's entirety for the sake of brevity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've correctly described, your `wine_rack` is an Array so you can't look up items using the name of a category like this: `wine_rack[:category]`.

One approach would be to use [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) to pick out the wines matching a category like this:

```
matching_wines = wine_rack.select { |wine| wine[:category].downcase == category }
```

You'd wrap that in your  function like this:

```
def wines_in_category(category)
  wine_rack.select { |wine| wine[:category].downcase == category }
end
```

and then use it like this:

```
suitable_wines = wines_in_category(user_category_selection)
for wine in suitable_wines
...
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense!  I was SO trying to fit a box into a round hole!

Comment: :-) glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution that points out what variables you have to work with.

Notice that you don't have the ability to interact with `wine_rack` directly from the method. You can use the `send` method to open the scope gate, or you can just pass in the `wine_rack` array.

Also, `Array#select` will return all the instances in which the block returns true. This may not affect your software now, but it could lead to issues later:

```
puts "Variables I have to work with: #{local_variables}"

def get_wine_information(passed_wine_rack,user_selection)
    puts "Variables I have to work with inside method: #{local_variables}"
    selection = passed_wine_rack.find {|wine| wine[:category] == user_selection}
    puts "#{selection[:vintage]} #{selection[:name]}, #{selection[:location]}"
    puts "#{selection[:grape_composition]}, rated #{selection[:personal_rating]} points"
end

#Scope Gate
Kernel.send(:define_method, :get_wine_info) do |user_selection|
    puts "Variables I have to work with inside scope gate: #{local_variables}"
end

#Calling just to see scope information
get_wine_info("")

get_wine_information(wine_rack,user_category_selection)
```